# How to convert maxwell equations to voltage and current equations?

Tags: circuit-analysis, electromagnetism

How to convert maxwell equations to voltage and current equations?

Or how to connect maxwell equations to voltage and current equations?

I find that curl B or E is using a function of time and B has 3 components B1(t), B2(t) and B3(t) if using curl to represent . This is what I confused about how plot this magnetic in maple or apply in circuit by set voltage and current to control magnetic and electric field. How to make this circuit ? Is there a diagram?

Comment: What you seem to be asking for is possible at a handwaving level, but that is all. We have three theories of electromagnetism: circuit theory, Maxwell's Equations, and QED, each with its own domain of applicability. It is best to select the right theory for your problem and stick to it. Combining bits and pieces from each can lead to a mess unless you are an expert. For example, talking in depth about electrons in the context of circuit theory.  Referring to your question, voltage as you are used to it in circuit theory is not even well-defined in some field contexts e.g. transmission lines.

Comment: Ramo, Whinnery, VanDuzer, "Fields and Waves in Communication Electronics". Chapters 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current already appears in Maxwell's equations, in the \$\vec{J}\$ term that is a source of magnetic fields.

Voltage, in the lumped-circuit approximation, is defined in relation to the electric field, by

$$V_{ba}=-\int_a^b \vec{E}\cdot{}{\rm d}\vec\ell.$$

Comment: In a way, KVL and KCL are low frequency approximations of Maxwell's field laws